# When a MySQL pool connection is released, should the connection stay open and would this affect max connections?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm working with MySQL more and ran into a question I can't seem to find an answer for without experimenting myself or looking much deeper.

I create a pool with MySQL and release properly, but I see the that there's an active connection still through MySQL Workbench till process is closed. Code example below:

```
        pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return callback(err);
        }
        if (args.length > 2) {
            sql_args = args[1];
        }
        connection.query(args[0], sql_args, (err, results) => {
            connection.release();
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return callback(err);
            }
            callback(null, results);
        });
    });
```

Is this normal behavior for the connection to remain open and if so, what happens if I had hundred servers connecting to this pool and all of them make a request but not all at once, and hit the max-connection limit with MySQL; Will there be a purge of inactive connections (not being used)?

*edit*
I'd wonder if the connections don't close would running a shorter TTL be ideal or some type of clearing? I'd like to have 100 servers fit in a 50 max connection and not error out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the implementation of the connection pool package.

Most connection pools in my experience allocate a fixed number of connections, open them, and keep them connected permanently for the life of the application. Connections are "lent" to client code that needs to access the database, and when the client code is done, the connection is returned to the pool, but it is not disconnected from MySQL.

If a connection drops by accident, the connection pool makes a new replacement connection, again so it can maintain a fixed number of ready connections. They remain connected permanently, as well as the CP can maintain them.

Yes, if you had 100 app servers that each allocate a pool of 20 connections, you would see 2000 clients connected on the MySQL Server all the time if you ran SHOW PROCESSLIST. We do see this regularly in production where I work.

Is that a problem? MySQL can handle a lot of connections if most of them are idle. We set our `max_connections` to 4096, for example. But rarely are more than 20-40 of them actually executing a query at any given moment. In fact, we made an alert that fires if the `Threads_running` goes over 100 on a given MySQL Server instance.

What if you had 100 app servers each of which made a CP of 500 connections? Yes, that would create 50000 connections on the MySQL Server, and that's probably more than it can handle. But why would you do that? The point of a connection pool is that many threads in your app can share a **small** number of connections.

So do be mindful that the total number of connections is basically your connection pool size multiplied by the number of app instances. And you might even have multiple app instances per app server (e.g. if you run sidecar processes and so on). So it can add up quickly. Do the math.

Comment: OP probably uses https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections, and indeed, _"when a previous connection is retrieved from the pool, a ping packet is sent to the server to check if the connection is still good"_.

Comment: So if no getting around max-connections could I ideally cancel them out manually after inactivity? I'd have many web-socket servers connecting to MySQL server and they don't need constant usage but periodic usage of the DB and vary queries at the times.

Comment: Just thinking of a dynamic approach to this to keep efficient because the query rate is low but lots connections idle and sometimes active. Considering performance costs/etc.

Comment: An idle connection shouldn't cost much to the database server. Are you seeing some cost associated with keeping extra connections open?

Comment: Reading the doc about the npmjs connection pool, I don't see any option to allow "stretching" the pool. If you use all the connections, it doesn't grow dynamically. The caller just gets queued, or else gets an error. Some other connection pool implementations might support dynamic pool sizing, but I don't know of one for node.js.

Comment: That should work and I don't actually, at least have yet to run that test! I do run the web-socket servers at one connection-limit in the pool so it's not to abusive but could be fair to raise that. Knowing all this!

Comment: I think I'll increase the connection max when necessary and optionally destroy the connection if it's not used in a minute.

Comment: You seem intent on releasing connections that are not used all the time. That's up to you, but I'm not sure what you'll be saving if you try to do that. For what it's worth, most developers don't bother with that level of micro-optimization.

Comment: Yes very intent on the micro optimizations and being efficient in environments where demand is not key for functionality. My HTTPS servers will not destroy to keep active, but chat-servers would cause they're active sometimes. Confusing stuff but I worry about all that stuff and appreciate you coming through with that information. It'll help loads! Already got ideas.

Comment: You might also consider implementing your own connection pool package that has two thresholds: one minimum (will always have at least this many connections open), and then if those are all occupied, keep opening connections until a max is reached (will not open more than this many connections). If an app's connection is closed between the min and max, then really close the db connection. Sort of like the [Apache MPM prefork module](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/prefork.html).

Comment: The fastest instruction is the one you don't execute. The things you don't do (like closing connections with superstitious belief that it helps) run at infinite speed.